# JSFL spritesheetexporter BUG

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, jsfl

I'm using jsfl to create my own customized spritesheet exporter.
I'm using the `fl.spritesheetexporter` class.
For some reason, every time I try to insert a name in the `addSymbol` method:

```
var exporter=new SpriteSheetExporter();
var obj=selection[i].libraryItem;
var name = "movieclip";
exporter.addSymbol(item,name);
```

I get an error:  "Argument number 1 is invalid";
 when i try only addSymbol(item) without parameters, it works fine and exports the spritesheet.

What should I do?

Comment: what is `item` pointing to ? the error suggests that is the problem, not name/"movieclip"

Comment: There are also other ways to create a custom spritesheet exporter. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: George - item is pointing to a selected item from the stage. var obj=selection[i].libraryItem . when i try only addSymbol(item) without parameters, it works fine and exports the spritesheet.

Comment: BotMaster - i want to create an automatic script that exports all the movieclips selected on stage to a a spritesheet and creates a JSON file with their x,y locations on stage so i can easily place the in an HTML5 game. i want the spritesheet object names to be their instance names and not their library names, like the SpriteSheetExporter automaticly does.

Comment: @user2664996 I haven't used Flash in a couple of years and haven't scripted with the SpriteSheetExporter, but the fact that you pass a library symbol might not help if you want to preserve the stage/instance names. Back then I wrote myself a [jsfl spritesheet exporter](http://lifesine.eu/rec/TPExporter.mov) making use of [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) which is a great sprite sheet utility and it's pretty affordable for how useful it is. In short I wrote a jsfl script that scrolled through the timeline and exported transparent png sequences using...

Comment: ...the symbol instance names and frames to compose the png filenames. Keeping the images in the correct order made it easy to import and manage in TexturePacker which dealt with packing, but also exporting a json file describing the sprite sheet. Is this roughly what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: yes. i also considered exporting frame-by-frame instead. but stil i want to understand why is the simple method of addSymbol() not working when i try to pass the name. according to adobe documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WSd5f4b6c52cfaa4b1-d3431961351cb0528c-7ffe.html it should work. thanks for your suggestion i will check it out.

Comment: In the documentation link you've sent I've spotted this: "symbol Object; The SymbolItem or SymbolInstance to include in the sprite sheet.". Have you tried passing a `SymbolInstance`(from stage) instead of a `SymbolItem`(from library) ? You should be able to get to the DOM, then timeline, layer and instance I guess or you can try [findObjectInDocByName()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7fb0CS5.html)

Comment: thanks @GeorgeProfenza, i used the symbol instance instead the libarry symbol and then i was able to modify the name of the movieclip added. here is my code:                                `var selectionArray = doc.selection;                              var results = fl.findObjectInDocByName(selectionArray[0].name, doc); 
var stageItem= results[0].obj; exporter.addSymbol(stageItem,stageItem.name,0,20);`

Comment: cool, you should also post this as the answer to your question so it could be easily spotted by others with the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I used the symbolinstance instead the library symbol and then i was able to modify the name of the movieclip added. here is my code:

```
     var doc = fl.getDocumentDOM();
     var selectionArray = doc.selection;
     var results = fl.findObjectInDocByName(selectionArray[0].name, doc);
     var stageItem= results[0].obj;
     exporter.addSymbol(stageItem,stageItem.name,1,20);
```